# Как разместить картинку на сайте так, чтобы в мобильной версии она обрезалась и оставался центр ее

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, img

На сайте нужно разместить картинку в пк версии вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

это я сделал, дальше нужно, чтобы в мобильной версии телефона, она становилась так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На всю ширину экрана, обрезавшись и имея четко лицо, не ноги и т.д

Со своим кодом я имею:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Она не обрезается, а становится меньше.
Мой код:

HTML

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <img src="../img/aboutUsGirl.png" width="100%" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Вариант с `img`

```css
.block {
  display: block;
  width: 75%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.block::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 75%;
}

.block img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <img src="//i.imgur.com/YvZWVz1.png">
</div>
```

Вариант на `background`

```css
.block {
  display: block;
  max-width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.block::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 75%;
}

.block::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url('//i.imgur.com/YvZWVz1.png') no-repeat center center / 200% auto;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вариант с object-position

```css
.img {
  max-width: 768px;
  margin: auto;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .img {
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .img img {
    width: 400px;
    height: 150px;
    object-position: -150px 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="img">
  <img src="https://bbmlive.com/adult/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/photo-1554949282-4f7f656833f0.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```